# Is fail2ban not matching these lines just because of the port?

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I would like fail2ban to engage against these lines and block the example IP address included:

```
[Tue Dec 08 12:17:13.622175 2015] [:error] [pid 30390] [client 62.210.88.201:38139] script '/var/www/html/httptest.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Dec 08 13:22:25.363614 2015] [:error] [pid 30386] [client 62.210.88.201:54141] script '/var/www/html/httptest.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Dec 08 14:36:01.790899 2015] [:error] [pid 28831] [client 62.210.88.201:42431] script '/var/www/html/httptest.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Fail2ban has been successfully configured to protect other services on this machine, but I can't seem to get it to run against those lines.

```
[apache-noscript]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-noscript
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 2
```

Is it just because "port = http,https" and should be "ports = all" ?

The relevant filter "apache-noscript.conf" was modified in the following way.

```
^%(_apache_error_client)s script '/\S*httptest\S*(\.php|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl)\S*' not found or unable to stat\s*$
```

Comment: `port` tells it which port(s) to block when IP addresses are banned by this rule and is not related to matching lines in log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the `port` part is not the problem. `port` is used to define to which port a banaction applies to after the regex rule is matched.

I guess your regex is not working the way it should be. You can use the [fail2ban-regex](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fail2ban-regex) command to see if it is really working and correct it if necessary. Here is a sample command:

```
fail2ban-regex '/var/log/apache*/*access.log' /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-noscript.conf
```

You can also use the following command to see jail status:

```
fail2ban-client status
```

Comment: Thank you! This answers my original question and provides a means for me to troubleshoot. I will update this question when an answer is found.